# header wont appear on all pages of crystal report 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to have a header appear on all the pages of a report designed in `crystal reports 2013`. Most of the reports will one page but occasionally they may be more.

In the section header I add the below to the suppress formula and leave the box unchecked.

```
If PageNumber<1 Then True
```

However, if there are two pages the header appears only on page one. Thank you :).

Comment: Which header are you talking about? Page header or report header or group header...can you please be specific

Comment: It is a `report header`, can a formula be used or can I simply change that to a group header? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report header will be added once for report, So there is no meaning to write that formula in report header.

Now as per your requirement.

Add fields in page header and also in group header.

Add the below supress formula for page header.

```
if pageheader =1
then true
else false
```

So in page one page header will be supressed and fields will be displayed as headings in group header.

From page 2 from starting of the page you will find the fields and only one problem with this solution is if group header starts from next page you will find two headers.

Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show some **Objects** on **all pages** then place **objects** on **Page Header**, If you want them to shown on Every group then place **objects** in **Group Header**, If you want to show them only on start of your report then place them in **Report Header**.

---